# WPF - How to right side align Menu control's MenuItems

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, menu, menuitem

I'm trying to right side align the MenuItems in WPF for a Menu control. I've already seen a solution through changing a registry value, but what I'm looking for is a clean WPF/XAML solution. Changing registry values also affects all application on the machine. A visual representation of what I'm trying to achieve

[image: menualignment]

Is this possible in WPF?

Edit:
Sorry, I didn't put here a specific sample, because nothing I've tried yet worked. I repositioned the menu items in many ways (up, right or centered :), but I wasn't able to establish the simple right side alignment shown on the picture. I currently trying to create control templates for menu and menu items. Maybe they will help.

Comment: I am also having the same problem. I want a menu to be aligned just like in this screenshot, yet nothing works. `RightToLeft` aligns to the rigth, yet all texts go to the right as well - BAD. There was this example of having some attached property `MenuPlacement` but it also failed, none of the options did the trick. Normally, this begaviour happens if menu wouldn't fit into the screen, however google chrome somehow has it working and it doesnt matter if it fits the screen.